# Getting "Hidden Elements" with DomDocument simple Web Scraping

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape some data from a website where there's a list of values with its sublists. However, the sublists are hidden untill I click them.

I can get the original list items using DomDocument and Xpath easy, but not the sublists.

I think the sublists are hidden through Javascript and I don't know how to simulate clicks this way.

How to get all list values??

Here's a pic for you to understand:

[image: Problem explanation throug picture]

The website is: http://www.econodata.com.br/lista-empresas/MINAS-GERAIS/BICAS

Current code:

```
$mpd = new DOMDocument();
$mainpage = "http://www.econodata.com.br/lista-empresas/MINAS-GERAIS/BICAS";
$mpd->loadHTML((new simple_html_dom())->load(collect_file($mainpage)));
$mpdXpath = (new DOMXPath($mpd));
foreach($mpdXpath->query('//div/ul/li/span') as $topicNode){
    echo $topicNode->textContent;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Expected output is all the sublists (the LetterNumbers like H49, H-492, etc, not just E, F, G, H...)

Comment: let us see your code, and what expected result?

Comment: Just added the info you asked for. About the "collect_file", its a function that gets all elements inside DOM using curl.

Comment: see updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all element has same class `parent`

```
<span style="float: left !important;" class="parent">A - AGRICULTURA,....</span>
```

extract using xpath `//span[@class="parent"]`

but if you also want to extract URLs

```
foreach($mpdXpath->query('//span[@class="parent"]/..') as $topicNode){
    $title = $topicNode->getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    $href = $topicNode->getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    echo $title->textContent;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "http://...." . $href->getAttribute('href');
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: That did it preciselly!